# Chatting With Facebook Friends Via Skype App

Tags: facebook, skype

I'm planning on taking a Windows Phone, and I was wondering if it is possible to talk to FB friends via the in-built Skype app, like you can do with the desktop application on a PC.

Can anyone please quickly confirm/deny this?

Comment: There is the Facebook Messenger app which is a lot better :)

Comment: Oh, no, I know of Messenger :)
I'm just curious if what I mentioned is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this feature exists in Skype for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but if you link your Microsoft and Facebook accounts I'm pretty sure this is possible, for friends that have both Skype and Facebook accounts.

You can definitely open someone's page in the Contacts application and Skype them from there.  I've also switched to a Skype video call from a regular phone call as well.

Comment: No, but...
Okay, if someone sends me a message on Facebook, will it show up on my Skype app?

This is possible with desktop application; even for Facebook friends who don't have Skype.

Comment: It doesn't seem to for me, but it does show on the Facebook Messenger app which works quite well...